# Number to be copied from cell with the same number format and show it as a label for a shape without any change in the number format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a cell in excel which contains a value, lets say 100000.
Now i want this value to have commas in between them to represent the thousands and millions i.e. 100,000. I can do this by changing the number format in the home menu.
Now i want this value to be copied from that cell and paste it as a label for a shape. When i am doing this the commas go away showing me just the numbers. 
I want it to happen through VBA but this is not happening in excel itself.

Does anyone have a plausible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In range object use Text property, like this:

```
Sheet1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("A1").Text
```

Comment: Ya this is fine. But i want to retain the number format that is present in the cell. For eg in cell A1 i have $10,000 (currency) and i want both the $ and commas in the text of the shape. This is what i am not able to do.

Comment: hmm... in my excel (2010) it working fine - copy value of cell with format. Are you sure you wite Range("A1").Text instead of Range("A1").Value?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was using value instead of text. it's working fine. thank you. :)